# Double parentheses in VB6 Array syntax (passed from .Net com-interop)

Tags: c#, arrays, vb6, com-interop

I have a C# dll exposed to vb6 via com-interop.  This is all working, but I am noticing something strange when I pass an array of a custom objects from .Net into VB6.

Accessing the array from VB6 is what baffles me.  If I access the array **directly** I have to do it like this:

```vb
Dim manager as New ObjectManager

'Access with two sets of parentheses:
msgbox manager.ReturnArrayOfObjects()(0).Name
```

However, if I copy the array first I can access it how I would normally expect to:

```vb
Dim manager as New ObjectManager
Dim objectArray() As CustomObject

'copy the array
objectArray = manager.ReturnArrayOfObjects

'access normally:
msgbox objectArray(0).Name
```

In the first case I had to use **two** sets of parentheses: `manager.ReturnArrayOfObjects()(0).Name`  In the second case I could just use **one** set of parentheses: `objectArray(0).Name`

Does anyone know why this is the case?  Am I doing something wrong here with the interop maybe?

Here is a quick stub/sample of the C# interop code.

```cs
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("[Guid here...]")]
public interface IObjectManager
{
    [DispId(1)]
    CustomObject[] ReturnArrayOfObjects();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("[guid here...]")]
public class ObjectManager: IObjectManager
{
    public CustomObject[] ReturnArrayOfObjects()
    {
        return new CustomObject[] { new CustomObject(), new CustomObject() };
    }
}
```

The class `CustomObject()` is also exposed to com-interop and working just fine.  Please let me know if you need me to post anymore code, but I think these little snippets represent the problem well enough to begin with.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ReturnArrayOfObjects()` in the C# code is a method. Your VB6 code is invoking the method, which returns the array, and then accessing the first element. The difference between this

```
msgbox manager.ReturnArrayOfObjects()(0).Name
```

and this

```
objectArray = manager.ReturnArrayOfObjects    
msgbox objectArray(0).Name
```

Is that in the second, you invoke the method by itself without accessing the first element, and VB is allowing you to leave off the parentheses from the method call. Conversely, the language is not allowing you to leave off the parentheses when you directly access the first element. It's simply a language feature, it's not a "double parentheses array syntax" issue.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems fairly obvious now that you explain it, but you wouldn't believe how long I racked my brain over this yesterday.  I really appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

`ReturnArrayOfObjects` is a method, that must be called. In VB6, if you're calling a method and supplying *no* parameters, and it's the entire statement, then you can omit the parenthesis.

However, in your first example, you're calling the method, and then indexing into the array returned by that method. You need the *first* set of parenthesis to indicate that you're passing no parameters to the method, and then the second set of parenthesis are being used for array indexing.

Comment: Thanks.  You are completely right as well.  I appreciate it.  Marked @Anthony Pegram as the correct answer, as he seemed to submit just a bit earlier.